# Is it possible to get rid of system volume overlay?

Tags: ios, volume

I have two buttons on a screen that are used to control system volume and every time they're pressed, the system volume indicator comes on and obscures them. Does anybody know if there's a way to make them disappear? (once of these things below if you don't know)

[image]